# Grid search preprocess multiple hyperparameters and multiple estimators

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Long term R user, learning Python.  I'm trying to use GridSearch to try different number of components for a PCA step in a pipeline as well as multiple estimators to.  I thought the code below was doing these (using the `GridSearch` documentation plus other sources) but the result of `best_params_` does not have preprocess params & estimator params; instead it prints `{'prep2__pcadtm__n_components': 3}` which indicates to me that he code is not doing what I thought it was.

- **Is the following code the way to test preprocessing with multiple hyperparameters and multiple estimators (plus hyper params) in the
  same GridSearch?**  *If not...*
- **How can I include preprocess with
  multiple hyperparameters and multiple estimators (plus hyper params)
  in the same GridSearch?**

#### MWE

```
## Dependencies
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    
## load data set
df = sns.load_dataset('mpg').drop(["name"], axis = 1).dropna()

## Factoize the outcome
factor = pd.factorize(df['origin'])
df.origin = factor[0]
definitions = factor[1]
outcome_order = definitions.tolist()

X = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['origin'])]
y = df.iloc[:,7].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 21) 


scaler = StandardScaler()
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
dtm_i = list(range(2, len(X_train.columns)))
dtm_i2 = list(range(0, len(X_train.columns)-2))

preprocess = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('scaler', scaler, dtm_i)], remainder='passthrough')
preprocess2 = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pcadtm', pca, dtm_i2)], remainder='passthrough')


pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('prep', preprocess),
    ('prep2', preprocess2),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
])


search_space = [
    {
       'prep2__pcadtm__n_components': [2, 3]
    },
    {
       'clf': [RandomForestClassifier()],
       'clf__max_depth': [5, 15]
    },
    {
       'clf': [KNeighborsClassifier()],
       'clf__n_neighbors' : [2, 3]
    }
]


# Create grid search
grid_imba = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = pipeline,
    param_grid = search_space,
    scoring = 'accuracy',
    cv = 3,
    return_train_score = True
)

## Fit the model using all the different estimators
grid_imba.fit(X_train, y_train);

## Extract best
best_params = grid_imba.best_params_
print(best_params)
```

```
##{'prep2__pcadtm__n_components': 3}
```

I thought that `GridSearch` would make 2 and 3 PCA component data sets and then pass this on to the next step with estimators. In turn, both of the PCA outputs would be tested with a Random Forest and then KNN [each of which has 2 hyper params.  Meaning 2 (PCA data sets for 2 & 3 components) X 2 (Estimators) X 2 (Hyper Params for each estimator) = 8 models being tested].  I think I am not correct.

Lastly, for efficiency, it'd be better if the `prep2` step wasn't computed each time a new estimator was tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when `param_grid` is a list of dictionaries, the search occurs over the *union* of the grids generated by each dictionary.  So your code actually checks six hyperparameter combinations:

- PCA dim 2, RandomForest default depth=None
- PCA dim 3, RandomForest default depth=None
- PCA defaults (dim2), RandomForest depth 5
- PCA defaults (dim2), RandomForest depth 15
- PCA defaults (dim2), KNN k=2
- PCA defaults (dim2), KNN k=3

You'd need something like

```py
search_space = {
    'prep2__pcadtm__n_components': [2, 3],
    'clf': [RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5),
            RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=15),
            KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2),
            KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)],
}
```

Depending on your actual needs, that of course might get unwieldy to list all the hyperparameter combinations you want for each different model.  In that case it might be simplest to nest searches:

```py
rf_gs = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=RandomForestClassifier(),
    param_grid={'max_depth': [5, 15]},
)
kn_gs = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
    param_grid={'n_neighbors': [2, 3]},
)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('prep', preprocess),
    ('prep2', preprocess2),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
])


search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipeline,
    param_grid={
        'prep2__pcadtm__n_components': [2, 3],
        'clf': [rf_gs, kn_gs],
    },
    scoring = 'accuracy',
    cv = 3,
    return_train_score = True    
)
```

This also has the effect of computing the preprocessors fewer times.  But see also the `memory` parameter of `Pipeline`.

Also, note that this approach changes the cv-folds fairly dramatically.  If you want a "flat" search, maybe write a quick script to generate the longer list in the first approach.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the correct approach, an alternative (The 2nd approach is easier mentally for me) and especially explaining what was actually happening.  Very helpful answer for shaping my mental conception.  Thanks for the time to pass on your knowledge and experience.  Much appreciated!